# Import custom package in python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

OK guys I can't find a solution anywhere for my problem, and I hope the solution is a simple one. Previously I had a flat file system for my gae project with no folders. I've been refactoring some code and I tried to put some in a folder. I'm a bit new and I've never done something like this before, but nothing on the internet suggests that I shouldn't easily be able to move my files into a folder. I added the `__init__.py` file to the folder and I import the folder name from my main program. However when I attempt to access a particular function in one of the files, it chokes and says `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'site1_ripper'`

here is my file structure:

```
main.py
SiteCrawlers\
    __init__.py
    site1_ripper.py
```

here are important parts of the files:

`main.py`

```
import SiteCrawlers
class Updater(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        SiteCrawlers.site1_ripper.siteCrawler()
```

`site1_ripper.py`

```
def siteCrawler()
    #stuff here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to explicitly import site1_ripper unless it's specified in `__init__.py`. Make your main import be:

```
import SiteCrawlers.site1_ripper
```

Comment: thanks this solved it. Could you expand on the "unless it's specified in `__init__.py`" part?

Comment: If your `__init__.py` file had the line `import site1_ripper` then it would be available when you imported the module overall. Take a look at sqlite3's [__init__.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/sqlite3/__init__.py?view=markup) in the standard library and try importing it in the python interpreter. Compare these two `import sqlite3 as s; dir(s)` and `import sqlite3.dbapi2 as t; dir(t)`. They should be nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

In your main file try:

```
from SiteCrawlers.site1_ripper import siteCrawler

class Updater(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        siteCrawler()
```

Comment: thanks for your input as well, but I used chmullig's solution